# Can I open a JavaFX dialog in my Java app?

Tags: java, javafx

I have written a Java application that opens a dialog (`FileChooser`) which runs fine on Windows but when I try and run it on the Pi, the dialog fails to appear.  What may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX on the Pi runs on a single primary JavaFX `stage`.  The implementation on Pi does not allow additional stages.  As such, you can't create secondary windows or dialogs that open in their own windows.  This is simply a restriction in the current release.  The release at which this restriction is present is at least:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```